# python/beautifulsoup/get_text().split() - how can I get connected text including blank value

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup

In short,
I need `"KBSTAR Fn K-뉴딜디지털플러스"` but I get three values `'KBSTAR', 'Fn', 'K-뉴딜디지털플러스'`

I need:

```py
['1501', 'KBSTAR Fn K-뉴딜디지털플러스', '11,830', '90', '-0.76%', '0', '95', '800', '0.00', '180', 'N/A', 'N/A']
```

but the result is like:

```py
['1501', 'KBSTAR', 'Fn', 'K-뉴딜디지털플러스', '11,830', '90', '-0.76%', '0', '95', '800', '0.00', '180', 'N/A', 'N/A']
```

Here is my code:
I am getting this because of blank in a data. But I don't know how to get connected words data without using split() method. Is there any way to get list data having blank in itself? Because most of the data have no blank itself

```py
stock_list = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "type_2"}).find("tbody").find_all("tr")
for stock in stock_list: 
    stock.get_text().split()
```

Below is my raw HTML

```html
<tr onmouseover="mouseOver(this)" onmouseout="mouseOut(this)" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                    <td class="no">1501</td>
                    <td><a href="/item/main.naver?code=368200" class="tltle">KBSTAR Fn K-뉴딜디지털플러스</a></td>
                    <td class="number">11,830</td>
                    <td class="number">
                <img src="https://ssl.pstatic.net/imgstock/images/images4/ico_down.gif" width="7" height="6" style="margin-right:4px;" alt="하락"><span class="tah p11 nv01">
                90
                </span>
            </td>
                    <td class="number">
                <span class="tah p11 nv01">
                -0.76%
                </span>
            </td>
                    <td class="number">0</td>
                                    <td class="number">180</td>
                                    <td class="number">800</td>
                                    <td class="number">95</td>
                    <td class="number">N/A</td>
                    <td class="number">N/A</td>
                    <td class="number">N/A</td>
                    <td class="center"><a href="/item/board.naver?code=368200"><img src="https://ssl.pstatic.net/imgstock/images5/ico_debatebl2.gif" width="15" height="13" alt="토론실"></a></td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: YOU know they are connected, but there's no particular reason they should be.  If you know you need everything from the 2nd item up through the first number, that's easy to do.  Or, you could look specifically for the `<a>` tag with class=title.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `split`? Just select for the td child elements. Use `strip` to tidy. The html looks a little off as well.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

tr_html = '''<tr onmouseover="mouseOver(this)" onmouseout="mouseOut(this)" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                    <td class="no">1501</td>
                    <td><a href="/item/main.naver?code=368200" class="tltle">KBSTAR Fn K-뉴딜디지털플러스</a></td>
                    <td class="number">11,830</td>
                    <td class="number">
                <img src="https://ssl.pstatic.net/imgstock/images/images4/ico_down.gif" width="7" height="6" style="margin-right:4px;" alt="하락"><span class="tah p11 nv01">
                90
                </span>
            </td>
                    <td class="number">
                <span class="tah p11 nv01">
                -0.76%
                </span>
            </td>
                    <td class="number">0</td>
                                    <td class="number">180</td>
                                    <td class="number">800</td>
                                    <td class="number">95</td>
                    <td class="number">N/A</td>
                    <td class="number">N/A</td>
                    <td class="number">N/A</td>
                    <td class="center"><a href="/item/board.naver?code=368200"><img src="https://ssl.pstatic.net/imgstock/images5/ico_debatebl2.gif" width="15" height="13" alt="토론실"></a></td>
                </tr>'''

soup = bs(tr_html, 'lxml')
[i.text.strip() for i in soup.select('td') if i.text.strip()]
```

Answer (score -1):

`str.split()` without `sep` argument splits the string by (consecutive) whitespace(s). Use `str.strip()` instead to remove leading and trailing whitespaces.